# Are MULTIPLE nullable foreign keys a bad practice?

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

So this has been asked a few times already but I didn't find any answer to having multiple nullable foreign keys in a table. 
As I understand the consensus is that nullable foreign keys are ok as long as they are not null for at least half the time.

The goal of my software is to aid the production department in different processes while building up a device. Let's call these processes **Config**, **Control** and **ExtendedBuildup**. Each one of these processes is unique for each device type and is represented in a separate table. A device may have one or more of these processes.
The process definition is linked to a device in a table called **DeviceType**. My **DeviceTypes** table has three nullable foreign keys (**IdConfig**, **IdControl** and **IdExtendedBuildup**).

When a device has been built by the production department the results are being stored in a table named **Device**. Each one of the processes named above also has a second results table that relates to the built up device. 
So that means the **Device** table also has three nulllable foreign keys named **IdConfigResult**, **IdControlResult** and **IdExtendedBuiltupResult**.

I kind of dislike having so many nullable foreign keys.
These nullable foreign keys could also be replaced by a link table for each table but this would mean that I would end up with the 3 process plus 3 results tables plus a link table for each one. That would mean I'd have 6 additional tables. No more nulls but waay more tables in general.
Inversing the relationship (moving the foreign key to the process or results table) is also an option but this would result in way more items in the processes table because if I update an entry in the **DeviceType** table (which results in a new entry as I need to have a full history of all changes made) I'd also have to create three new entries, one for each process.

In the future there might also be some new processes that would have to integrate into this schema so creating a new process will always mean that there has to be some new tables and relations.

So what should I do preferrably? I'm really at a conflict here as I can't see any proper solution that solves all the problems I have.

Comment: "As I understand the consensus is that nullable foreign keys are ok as long as they are not null for at least half the time." - I am not aware of any such "rule" and even if it existed, there should be accompanying guidance that should tell you *under what conditions* that rule generally applies and *under what conditions* it doesn't. If you don't understand the applicability of rules then you're just blindly applying them and that doesn't make for good outcomes. If that's your only problem, I'd suggest the easiest solution is to ignore that "rule".

Comment: I can't find where I read this but it was on a similiar discussion here on stackoverflow (was the answer to said discussion). I'd also go for ignoring this "rule" but I'd have liked to see a different opinion on this topic

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum and questions seeking *opinions* are generally frowned upon.

Comment: There's no such consensus, rule or opinion. Foreign key *constraints* are meant to enforce business/logical constraints. They have nothing to do with value distribution. A nullable FK means that a device may or may not be related to only *one* ConfigResult. A many-to-many table, which you call "link table" can't enforce this business constraint so it's a bad choice. It could enforce a 1-to-many constraint, if the `DeviceID` column had a unique constraint.